# Loading data into BigQuery from Cloud Storage using Cloud Function (Alternative to functions?)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions, etl

I'm currently loading data from a `csv` file in Cloud Storage to BigQuery using a Cloud Function.

However, Cloud Functions have a timeout limit and I expect these files to get big enough where it will cause issues.

In addition, inserting into big query is limited to `10mb/insert_rows`.

What else can I use instead of Cloud Functions to get this working?
Need it to be triggered upon file drop into Cloud Storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are inserting files from a .CSV use a batch load job. Asking BigQuery to load a file is a sub-second job, and BigQuery will proceed loading them in an async mode.

These loads are free, and your cloud function won't need to wait for it to finish.

You will be able to set up a notification that calls the cloud function each time a new file is dropped into your GCS bucket.

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv

Comment: Awesome! What if I need to add some logic on top of this? Such as...delete all data between a date range so the incoming file will insert the latest data for those dates.

Comment: well, you can add any logic you need in the query or in the function... not sure what logic you need

Comment: Felipe is right. Using a load job instead of streaming it would be much easier/better. The only thing is that because the job is async, monitoring its status (and handling possible failed load jobs) is something you'll need to think about. You could hang back in your function and poll, but you're still constrained by the 9m timeout. Another way is to offload the ingestion/processing to Dataflow instead. So, `File -> GCS -> Function -> Dataflow (template) -> BigQuery`.

Comment: Got it. So I'm still using cloud functions, but a different method of inserting the data.
This means I can run the delete query before I load data, as well as manipulate it with pandas.

Comment: Check out my lazy data loading tips: https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-lazy-data-loading-ddl-dml-partitions-and-half-a-trillion-wikipedia-pageviews-cd3eacd657b6

Comment: Cool, that's pretty helpful. Wondering how you would approach this if you did have to work with a dataframe.